# Event delegation on parent only works with some events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, event-delegation

Why am I able to listen to certain events using event delegation on `window.parent.document` but not others? Specifically I found that I was able to listen to a button's click event, but trying to do the same for the jQueryUI's [dialogbeforeclose](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event wouldn't trigger the event handler.

For example binding to a click event for a button like the following worked

```
  $(window.parent.document).on('click', '#btnTest', function () {
         alert('Button clicked');
   });
```

However trying to listen to the custom jQuery UI `event` like the following doesn't (the same code works on the parent page itself when binding to the document)

```
$(window.parent.document).on('dialogbeforeclose', function () {
       alert('Dialog closing');
 });
```

But binding it to the parent's body instead does

```
 window.parent.$('body').on("dialogbeforeclose", function(event, ui) {
      alert('Bound on body');
  });
```

For some additional context, I have a parent html page that has a jQuery UI dialog which has a iFrame within it.

Parent HTML

```
   <div id="btnCnt">
        <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Test 2"/>
    </div>

    <div id="popUpCnt" >
        <iframe id="frmTest">

        </iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you're using `$` from the child page rather than the parent. jQuery bases a lot of it's actions on the current document, which would be the document of the page that the `$` you are using was defined on.

Comment: I actually thought about that, but why would it make a difference? and why would it work for some event?

Comment: sorry, i updated my comment. To know the *why* we'd have to go to the source.

Comment: You seem to be correct, I just tried testing it using the parent's jQuery object and it worked. Do you know where I might some more information on that?

Comment: My point was that the fact that you bound it to the body is irrelevant. You could have just as well bound it to the document for the same effect, what made the difference is what instance of `$` you used.

Comment: Your saying by binding it to the parent's `body` that causes the parent's `$` instance to be used? Why?

Comment: No, `$(` vs `window.parent.$(`

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't even realize that I was doing that, I meant to just bind it to the body (basically doing a `.find()`.

Comment: I guess then that jQuery puts some of the event information in its instance instead of the DOM. I tried to find that information in the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but I didn't see anything along those lines. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Exactly. i'm working on a sample and answer that better explains, it's a bit too much for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an event is triggered using .trigger() (which is the case for custom events) jQuery goes through and triggers the events that are stored in that instance of jQuery's data cache. Since you bound to the event with a different instance of jQuery than the one that triggered the event, your event handler was never triggered. For example, see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EJg8b/

```
jq2 = $.noConflict();
jq1 = $;

jq1('body').on('click', function () {
  console.log('jq1 click event!');
});
jq2('body').on('click', function () {
  console.log('jq2 click event!');
});

jq1('body').on('myCustomEvent', function () {
  console.log('jq1 myCustomEvent event!');
});
jq2('body').on('myCustomEvent', function () {
  console.log('jq2 myCustomEvent event!');
});

function onButtonClick() {
  jq1('button').trigger('myCustomEvent');
}
```

Because the custom event was triggered with `jq1`, only the event bound with `jq1` was able to receive it. The click on the other hand was a native event, and therefore was picked up by both.